# Property 'setCurrentUser' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339) with useContext

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I was trying to pass useState properties through `Context.Provider value={{theme, setTheme}}` as it was written in tutorial, and after receive it with `useContext(Context)`, but it keeps returning me an **error**:

```
const setCurrentUser: any
Property 'setCurrentUser' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)
```

**Note:** This code is fully copied from [react docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useContext) with little type additions to see if it's me how's making such mistake, or I just don't know how to fix it

I [checked](https://dev.to/madv/usecontext-with-typescript-23ln) usage `useContext` with TypeScript, but code there is the same as mine and doesn't provide me an answer

**Full code:**

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState, ReactNode, DetailedHTMLProps, ButtonHTMLAttributes, MouseEventHandler } from 'react';

const CurrentUserContext = createContext<Object>({});

export default function MyApp() {
      const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
      return (
            <CurrentUserContext.Provider
                  value={{
                        currentUser,
                        setCurrentUser
                  }}
            >
                  <Form />
            </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
      );
}

function Form(): JSX.Element {
      return (
            <Panel title="Welcome">
                  <LoginButton />
            </Panel>
      );
}

function LoginButton(): JSX.Element {
      const {
         //\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
         // Error occurs here   

            currentUser,
            setCurrentUser

         ///\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
      } = useContext(CurrentUserContext);

      if (currentUser !== null) {
            return <p>You logged in as {currentUser.name}.</p>;
      }

      return (
            <Button onClick={() => {
                  setCurrentUser({ name: 'Advika' })
            }}>Log in as Advika</Button>
      );
}

interface PanelProps {
      title: string
      children: ReactNode
}

function Panel({ title, children }: PanelProps): JSX.Element {
      return (
            <section className="panel">
                  <h1>{title}</h1>
                  {children}
            </section>
      )
}

interface ButtonProps extends DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement> {
      children: ReactNode
      onClick?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>
}

function Button({ children, onClick }: ButtonProps): JSX.Element {
      return (
            <button className="button" onClick={onClick}>
                  {children}
            </button>
      );
}
```

If this wording of the question is not correct, please let me know

Comment: you've set the type of  `CurrentUserContext` to `Object` (L#3), where it's supposed to be explicit object structures (or `any`). take a look at the [TS docs on object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types)

Comment: Thanks. I can't mark your comment as useful because don't enough reputation. If you write this as answer, I'll mark as a right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `CurrentUserContext` is set to `Object` (L#3), where it's supposed to be explicit object structures (or `any`)

Take a look at the [TS docs on object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types)

```js
createContext<{
    currentUser: string, 
    setCurrentUser: fn(_:any) => void 
}>
```

Should be the approximate type you're looking for. I have no way to tell for sure.

But this gets messy, so consider [instantiating as suggested by H294](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75461370/13982210). Or using a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html)

Answer (score 1):

at this line

```
const CurrentUserContext = createContext<Object>({});
```

adding initContextValue

```
const initContextValue = {
  currentUser: {name: 'abc'},
  setCurrentUser: ({name: 'abc'}) => {}
}
const CurrentUserContext = createContext<Object>(initContextValue);
```

y will see the TS can work